# Arch test failing STANDARD_STREAMS

Tags: java, stream, archunit

I have app which folowing by archunit rules and I get:

> NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_ACCESS_STANDARD_STREAMS

failed rule - it's mean I can't use standard Java I/O Streams. But what I can use instead?

How I can avoid this architecture rule with another Java methods instead standard streams? Because My arch rules are failing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [Oracle blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/unit-test-your-architecture-with-archunit) says:

> The Library API also contains the GeneralCodingRules class, which includes predefined and self-describing static coding rules that are common in many Java projects, for example:
>
> NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_ACCESS_STANDARD_STREAMS (that is, the System.out, System.err, and printStackTrace methods: use a logging library instead)

So I think you need remove all println `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 2):

The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_ACCESS_STANDARD_STREAMS`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.14.1/com/tngtech/archunit/library/GeneralCodingRules.html#NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_ACCESS_STANDARD_STREAMS), says:

> It is generally good practice to **use correct logging instead of writing to the console**.
>
> - Writing to the console cannot be configured in production
> - Writing to the console is synchronized and can lead to bottle necks
>
> For information about checking this rule, refer to [GeneralCodingRules](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/0.14.1/com/tngtech/archunit/library/GeneralCodingRules.html).

You asked how to avoid this architecture rule. Just do what it says: ***Use logging!***